# How to Mock Static Methods in Easymock

Tags: android, unit-testing, easymock

It is easy to mock an interface method which is implemented by some class but if there is a class and having a static method than how we can mock it with the help of easymock??

supose the is a class A and having a void retrurned method as public static void methodA(some args..){}

```
    class A {
public static void methodA(//some args..){
//some logic
}
}
```

How we can mock A's method  methodA with the help of EasyMock

Comment: Nope you can't. You'll need the help of some other libraries like the `Powermock` (can work in tandem with `easymock`). `Jmockit` is one great library that provides the static mocking feature among many others that make it arguably the best mocking library.

Answer (score 0):

As mystarrocks mentioned in the comment, you can mock static methods using [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), even you can test final class/method and private methods too!

From the documentation:

> PowerMock is a framework that extend other mock libraries such as
>   EasyMock with more powerful capabilities. PowerMock uses a custom
>   classloader and bytecode manipulation to enable mocking of static
>   methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods,
>   removal of static initializers and more.

For example:

```
public class IdGenerator {

   /**
    * @return A new ID based on the current time.
    */
   public static long generateNewId() {
      return System.currentTimeMillis();
   }
}
```

Then you can mock this static method using:

```
// This is the way to tell PowerMock to mock all static methods of a
// given class
mockStatic(IdGenerator.class);

/*
 * The static method call to IdGenerator.generateNewId() expectation.
 * This is why we need PowerMock.
 */
expect(IdGenerator.generateNewId()).andReturn(expectedId);
```

Check [Mocking static methods](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) for the complete example.